# markdown to pdf - center image

Tags: latex, markdown, center

I have a markdown file with numerous images that displays great in visual studio code.
I created the markdown file in R by scraping a section of our agencies legacy website.

The last step is to convert this md to pdf for archiving. I am doing this step in R

```
rmarkdown::pandoc_convert(here::here("myfile.md"),output="myfile.pdf")
```

The process completes, everything looks good except that the images are not centered and the figure captions do not display under the image (they wrap).
The code i am using for the images in markdown is

```
![label](figures/fig1.png) Figure 1 Time series of stuff
```

If i use html to center the image in markdown then the conversion to pdf doesn't display properly. If i enclose the figure with

```
\begin{figure} or \begin{center}
\end{figure} or \end{center}
```

then the conversion fails with an error.

Any advice. Spent too much time already reading articles not applicable

Comment: If you use R and/or RStudio I would suggest to write in rmarkdown and use `knitr::include_graphics()` and the chunck option `fig.align = "center"`. So you are independent from your HTML or PDF output.

Comment: @J_F thanks for your suggestion. I am creating the md file on the fly, by parsing a ton of html code. I have a live md viewer to view parsing output. I don't need any R functionality in the markdown and i can't visualize rmd output without constantly knitting. I find this annoying, so i use md instead. I was originally going to go this route but opted against it.

Comment: As a work around i used Visual Studio Code to convert the md to pdf. No issues at all. The formatting looks better too.